# Check if given value exists in array or mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to check if a given value exists in a mysql table. If yes; I would like to get the value of another column of that row.

Now I have:

```
$teinsertengetal=$_GET['getal'];
    
    // start
    
    $i = 0;
    $ikhadingezetArray = array();
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT getal, hoevaakingezet FROM ingezettegetallen");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $ikhadingezetArray[$i]['getallen'] = $row['getal'];
        $ikhadingezetArray[$i]['hoevaakingezets'] = $row['hoevaakingezet'];
        $i++;
    }
    
    foreach($ikhadingezetArray as $value)
    {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
```

My problem is that the foreach only echos "Array", not the values within the array.
And then I have to check if $teinsertengetal is in the array (the field "getal" in $ikhadingezetArray). If yes; I want the value of "hoevaakingezet" from the same row number of the array.

I hope you understand what I mean. Maybe it's not the best way I could do this?
Thank you in advance!

edit: the echo is just to check if the right values were inserted in the array.

For example:

Table "ingezettegetallen"

| getal | hoevaakingezet |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2 |
| 48 | 4 |

$teinsertengetal = 48

Now I would like check if 48 is in the column "getal". If yes (and it is in this example) I would like to store the value "4" in a variable (like $hoevaakingezetdus).

Comment: `$ikhadingezetArray` is a 2-dimensional array, so `$value` is an array. You can't echo an array, use `var_dump($value)` or print the columns that you want.

Comment: If you want to test if a value exists in the table add a `WHERE` clause to the query instead of fetching the entire table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the check in the query, rather than fetching the entire table.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT hoevaakingezet 
    FROM ingezettegetallen
    WHERE getal = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $teinsertengetal);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['hoevaakingezet'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking some time for me Barmar! Unfortunately I cannot check if this works for me now, but tomorrow I can. I will let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a while loop? Because I know it can only be max 1 result.
When there are no results, I want to give $hoevaakingezetdus the value 0. If there is 1 result, I want $hoevaakingezetdus to be filled with the value of $row['hoevaakingezet']
Thank you!

Comment: If there's only one row then you don't need the loop.